Application.OnTime not executing following Sub in an orderly manner
I am trying to write a simple VBA in excel to run through a loop of stock tickers and update certain data from Bloomberg API, but the code seems not to be working appropiately.
Sub RunMacroForDropdown()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Worksheets("Selector").Range("B6:B42")
        Range("B1").Value = r.Value
        RefreshData
    Next r
End Sub
Sub RefreshData()
    Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"
    Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
    'Wait until it Downloads the information
    Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")), "ProcessData"
End Sub
Sub SaveWorkbook()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Path = "\\Client\C$\CitrixExchange"
    FileName = Range("B1").Value & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Path & FileName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Sub ProcessData()
MsgBox ("Processing Data for" & Range("B1").Value)
'Wait for a while until it processes data
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        SaveWorkbook
End Sub

When debugging, the OnTime process returns to the 'Next r' in the RunMacroForDropdown, and does not enter the ProcessData function.
Thanks for your help!

When you call RefreshData in the first sub, it schedules a run of ProcessData in 3 seconds and returns immediately. Your sub then continues to loop.
Your best option would be to use the VBA API and call the BB API synchronously from VBA instead of waiting for the asynchronous data population in the spreadsheet.
But if you want to stick to your approach, you should only run refreshData for the first cell. Once ProcessData completes, you can rerun refreshData for the next cell etc.
Also note that waiting 3 seconds may or may not work, so in ProcessData you should check if the data has updated, and if not use an OnTime to run again a bit later.

Thank you for your fast response. As I am not a proficient user of VBA, I believe sticking to calling the asyncrhonous data population with "RefreshEntireWorkbook" would be easier, as calling the BB API syncrhonously offers much more control, but comes at the expense of much harder coding.
How may I capture ProcessData completion in VBA? Or how may I check the data has been succesfully updated? Thanks beforehand!

You can check the value of the cell, for example if the first character is #(LEFT(Bloomberg_cell.Value, 1)="#").
